# How to properly use an Author's name in the Text

Tags: citing, author

I want to use the name of an author from my sources in the plain text as small capitals. Can I achieve this by referencing to the bibtex or do I have to stick with the "hard coded" name.

This is what I want:

> As EINSTEIN wrote in his source bla blub. [EIN04]

This is what I do:

> ```
> As \textsc{Einstein} wrote in his source bla blub.\cite{Einstein1904}
> ```

This is what I somehow want to do:

> ```
> As \somecommand{Einstein1904} wrote in his source bla blub. \cite{Einstein1904}
> ```

Does anybody know if there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you use bibtex or biblatex/Biber to create the formatted bibliography. If you use bibtex, please also reveal which bibliography style you employ, and whether you use a citation management package such as `natbib`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use biblatex this MWE should demonstrate how to access the author's name from the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{my.bib}
@article{einstein1905,
    author =       {Einstein, Albert},
    title =        {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper},
    journal =      {Annalen der Physik},
    volume =       {322},
    number =       {10},
    year =         {1905},
}

@article{zweiDreistein2019,
    author =       {Zweistein, Anton and Dreistein, Berta},
    title =        {Neuste Erkenntnisse},
    journal =      {Annalen der Astrologie},
    volume =       {1},
    number =       {1},
    year =         {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{document}
\citename{einstein1905}{author} said: \ldots

\citename{zweiDreistein2019}{author} said: \ldots

\citeauthor{einstein1905} said: \ldots

\citeauthor{zweiDreistein2019} said: \ldots

Name in small caps:

\newcommand{\albertEinstein}{\textsc{\citename{einstein1905}{author}}}
\albertEinstein{} said: \ldots

\newcommand{\einstein}{\textsc{\citeauthor{einstein1905}}}
\einstein{} said: \ldots
\end{document}
```